# Значення слова "забанити"

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова

Часто ми використовуємо слово ***"забанити"***. Наприклад, [тут](http://ua.smart-ip.net/what-to-do-if-i-was-banned), [тут](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/9/1480982338952793575/) і [тут](https://ua.censor.net.ua/photo_news/3070217/kyyivskogo_hudojnyka_yermolenka_zabanyly_v_facebook_pislya_publikatsiyi_alternatyvnyh_plakativ_do_chs2018).

Також з останнього посилання наводжу контекст:

> Київського художника Єрмоленка **забанили в Facebook** після публікації альтернативних плакатів до ЧС-2018.

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zabanyty) цього слова немає.

То яке ж насправді значення слова ***"забанити"***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [Словнику комп’ютерного сленгу](http://odb.km.ua/?dep=1&dep_up=563&dep_cur=1705) знаходимо:

> **Забанити** – заборонити написання повідомлень у форум або чат, заборонити доступ до будь-якого ресурсу.

У [Словнику для новачків (сайт про те як стати хакером)](http://fuck-hack.com/slovnyk-dlya-novachkiv-chastyna-2/):

> **Забанити**, забабить заборонити користувачеві написання повідомлень в форум або чат (від англ. to ban), заборонити доступ до якого-небудь ресурсу (наприклад, «забанити .mp3 файли на проксе»).

Також знаходимо інформацію у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0):

> **Бан** (англ. ban, /bæn/ — забороняти, оголошувати поза законом) — один з прийнятих в Інтернеті способів контролю за діями користувачів. Як правило, бан полягає в обмеженні певних прав користувача (на створення/відправлення нових повідомлень або створення нових тем на веб-форумі, на відправлення повідомлень в чаті, на коментування в блогах та ін.).